# Layout progress bars in-between nodes - HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists, flexbox

I'm trying to build a stepping wizard form layout with a bar at the top of the page containing a dynamic number of steps (nodes) and progress bars connecting the nodes. I'm having trouble getting the progress bars and nodes to cooperate.

The idea is to have each nodes spaced evenly on the page horizontally (already working nicely using flexbox), and the progress bars fluidly filling the gaps between the nodes.

I am currently trying to use an `<li>` to contain each iteration of the progress bar & `<a>` pairs, but it is not laying out like I need it to (the progress bars are not behaving fluidly and not filling empty space between the `<a>` tags).

Is this the best way to lay this out?

Just though I'd confirm this is the best way to lay these out before going any further.

EDIT 1 (Clarifying goal):

This image is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

The progress bar and red `<a>` node are both within the same `<li>`. I have given the progress bar a width of 90% for this example but the goal is to only assign a width to the red `<a>` node and have the project bar fluidly fill the remaining space.

Below is the HTML & SCSS I am currently using:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-title">Project Milestones</div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="milestone-bar">
      <li>
        <div class="progress project-progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100.0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100.0%;">
            100%
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/projects/24?milestone=18">Milestone 1</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="progress project-progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100.0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100.0%;">
            100%
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/projects/24?milestone=39">Milestone 3</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="progress project-progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50.0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50.0%;">
            50%
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/projects/24?milestone=48">Milestone 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
ul.milestone-bar {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  display: flex;
  li {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;;
    a {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      font-size: 12px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      background-color: red;
      float:right;
      &:hover {
        background: none;
        border: 4px solid blue;
      }
      &:active {
        background-color: darkblue;
      }
      &:focus {
        background-color: green;
      }
    }
    .project-progress {
      background-color: #d3d3d3;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Is this on the right track?

Below is a snippet of the above:

```css
ul.milestone-bar {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  display: flex;
}
ul.milestone-bar li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.milestone-bar li a {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}
ul.milestone-bar li a:hover {
  background: none;
  border: 4px solid blue;
}
ul.milestone-bar li a:active {
  background-color: darkblue;
}
ul.milestone-bar li a:focus {
  background-color: green;
}
ul.milestone-bar li .project-progress {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-title">Project Milestones</div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="milestone-bar">
      <li>
        <div class="progress project-progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100.0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100.0%;">
            100%
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/projects/24?milestone=18">Milestone 1</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="progress project-progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100.0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100.0%;">
            100%
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/projects/24?milestone=39">Milestone 3</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="progress project-progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50.0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50.0%;">
            50%
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/projects/24?milestone=48">Milestone 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188600/using-css-calc-with-step) is what you want?

Comment: Hi @kukkuz, thanks for your reply. This is not what I am after, I am looking to put a progress bar in between each node, not a line.

Comment: so you found what you desired?

Comment: Perhaps you could show us what this is supposed to look like and some code showing where you are so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I did some changes to your code:

1. Added `flex` to each `li` to create nested flex children here:

   ```
   ul.milestone-bar li {
     width: 100%;
     list-style: none;
     display: flex;
   }
   ```
2. Added `flex: 1` for it to flex to the whole width and vertically align it to the center using `align-self: center` to your `project-progress` like this:

   ```
   ul.milestone-bar li .project-progress {
     background-color: #d3d3d3;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0;
     flex: 1;
     align-self: center
   }
   ```
3. Added the progress bar style:

   ```
    ul.milestone-bar li .project-progress .progress-bar {
       background: #0095FF;
       text-align: center;
    }
   ```
4. Also adjusted the `milestone-bar` to look better:

   ```
   ul.milestone-bar li a {
     width: 60px;
     height: 60px;
     font-size: 10px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background-color: red;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 60px;
   }
   ul.milestone-bar li a:hover {
     background: none;
     border: 4px solid blue;
     line-height: 52px;
   }
   ```
5. To top it up, used `box-sizing: border-box` to all elements in the page for better management of border especially to remove the 'jumps' when you hover.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul.milestone-bar {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  display: flex;
}
ul.milestone-bar li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
ul.milestone-bar li a {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}
ul.milestone-bar li a:hover {
  background: none;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  line-height: 52px;
}
ul.milestone-bar li a:active {
  background-color: darkblue;
}
ul.milestone-bar li a:focus {
  background-color: green;
}
ul.milestone-bar li .project-progress {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center
}
ul.milestone-bar li .project-progress .progress-bar {
    background: #0095FF;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-title">Project Milestones</div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="milestone-bar">
      <li>
        <div class="progress project-progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100.0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100.0%;">
            100%
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/projects/24?milestone=18">Milestone 1</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="progress project-progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100.0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100.0%;">
            100%
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/projects/24?milestone=39">Milestone 3</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="progress project-progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50.0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50.0%;">
            50%
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/projects/24?milestone=48">Milestone 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what I was after and works perfectly, thank you very much @kukkuz. The progress bar styling looks much better too.